# Two nodejs applications, one mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good day! I have created an application using nodejs + mongoose and now I want to make something like a superuser application. I need my admin panel application to connect to the same database. So, i have a question.

Should i store the same Schema file in both applications to have an ability to use my Schema methods? In other words, what is the best way to create one more API using the same db?

Thank you!

Comment: Could the admin app just be some additional pages for your current app? Perhaps add some role permissions as needed.

Comment: No, it can't for security reasons. Just 2 apps with 1 db. I was making it first as you said, but this solution was declined by other team members. So, I had to ask it on stack overflow :/

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, why not create another service that only interacts with the database? That way, the systems will refer to the same schema/DB regardless of which application you want to connect to it. So the superuser application and the normal application will just query the DB microservice that interacts the database.

Pro: source of truth for the schema for all applications and the DB queries will just be API calls

Con: additional overhead in creating your ecosystem

Comment: Haha, nice, I've asked this question 5 years ago :) Actually 5 years ago I didn't have the possibility to do that for some reasons. But nowadays I'd do it with the MicroService, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the same DB from two different applications, you will want to make sure those schemas are the same between the two. If one changes its inputs, the other might need to change its display (or risk not expecting all that information). Keep all this in mind during your release process.

I would suggest making the schemas an external library to both, or have the admin panel require the current app. You'll avoid getting two sets out of sync and know to look at one place for the schema definitions.

Comment: Thnak you for your answer! I did what i wanted, but there is one more little question. Is it somehow possible to get a schema which was created in one application with mongoose in another app? So it would always be sync? It would be a quite good solution as i think :)

Comment: That was the suggestion of the separate library. First way: Create a new project that only contains your schemas and be sure they are exported. Then have both apps require that new project.  Second way: Require the first app in your admin app, and use the schemas directly from the first app. The second suggestion feels like more overhead than the first.